# Laws of predicate calculus: Proofs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

[Link to question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzoN4.png)

***I will provide the laws below along with what I have done so far.***
[First half of laws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QR722.png)
[second half of laws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irJT1.png)
[This is what I have done so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0uad.jpg)
***I am aware I need to get an extra negation sign around the whole equation but I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.***

Comment: Ok, apply same rule to right-hand side followed by De Morgan, Distributivity and rules for $\text {true}$ and the result will be the same as the left-hand side.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA hi, is there any chance you could type out the next 2 steps for me? I tried to use De Morgans law but it switches the "or" into an "and" and i am not sure what to do after.

Comment: The LHS is $(\lnot X \lor (\lnot Y \lor Z))$ while the RHS is $(X \land \lnot Y) \lor (\lnot X \lor Z)$. APplying Distributivity to the RHS you get: $(X \lor \lnot X \lor Z) \land (\lnot Y \lor \lnot X \lor Z)$.